# How to enable backend layout selection for users

Tags: typo3-9.x

I create a site based on Typo3 9.5.12 / Bootstrap Package 11.0.2.

I need to enable my editors to select a backend layout for new pages (!).

So far I did not find a way to do so. Setting Page TSConfig for the editors group like so gives me the following result:

```
page.TCEFORM {
    pages {
        abstract.disabled = 1
        backend_layout.disabled = 0
        backend_layout_next_level.disabled = 0
    }
}
```

Abstract field is disabled as expected.
Backend Layout cannot be selected. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you granted access to these fields in the BE-Group definition?

[image: list pages]
[image: write pages]
[image: edit pages fields]